# XMPP starter - with java

Tags: java

Please help me in getting started with XMPP as i am going to start working on a Java project soon and I will be implementing this protocol. I need to get started soon but couldnt find enough resources online. Please suggest few things like : giving input to the server and then receiving the msg back, communication with the ISB and client-xmpp-xlient. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135112/xmpp-starter-with-java please delete one of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an existing Java implementation. Check out [SMACK](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). If it fits your licensing needs, then I would use something like that before writing all the code yourself.

Comment: whats the need for this smack API? what does it do actually?

Comment: Implements XMPP protocol for yourself.

Comment: Hi @Pablo Santa Cruz. Hildebrand. I've been trying to create an XMPPConnection but the the connection fails. The XMPPServer starts OK, though. Could you please look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245311/xmppconnection-doesnt-connect) and see if you can help? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of using XMPP [here](http://frequency62.blogspot.com/2009/11/gtalk-status-message-fun-gtalk-uses.html) using Smack API

raj