# XMPP starter - with java

Tags: java, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XMPP starter - with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135040/xmpp-starter-with-java)

Please help me in getting started with XMPP, as I am going to start working on a Java project soon and I will be implementing this protocol. I need to get started soon but I couldn't find many resources online. How do I give input to the server and then receiving the msg back? How do I communicate with the ISB and client-xmpp-xlient? Any other basic suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate. User should have edited his previous question instead of opening a very similar new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Smack XMPP client API for your project?

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp

Comment: Hi @Brian Showalter. I've been trying to create an XMPPConnection but the the connection fails. The XMPPServer starts OK, though. Could you please look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245311/xmppconnection-doesnt-connect) and see if you can help? thank you in advance.